# Using get instead of post in a form to work with a url like index.php?page=homepage

Tags: php, html

I have three pages that has forms on them. They all lead to one another. The first page has a form that goes to page two and queries a database. I understand that a POST method *should* be used here (according to [RFC1866 section 8.2.3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt)) But I want to implement a GET method to this page because when a user is on page two they will select their options there and go to page three, *but* when a user is on page three they may need to use the browser back button to go back to page two to change some values. If POST method was used it would prompt the user to "resubmit" and I was hoping to avoid this.

```
 ?page=one          ?page=two         ?page=three
 __________         __________        __________
|          |       |          |      |          |
|          |       |          |      |          |
|  Page 1  |  ==>  |  Page 2  | ==>  |  Page 3  |
|          |       |          | <==  |          |
|          |       |          |      |          |    
|__________|       |__________|      |__________|
```

The problem I was facing was the problems with the URLs, when setting action to "?page=two" the input names doesn't get picked up and put into the URL like it would if I were to set the action to "pagetwo.php" (this would turn into pagetwo.php?data=x). How can I come around this obstacle?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not clear on the issue. Can you please explain the scenario further -- "when setting action to "?page=two" the input names doesn't get picked up and put into the URL like it would if I were to set the action to "pagetwo.php". What do you mean by input names?

Comment: When I set the action to a page like "index.php?page=two" I was hoping on submit the URL would turn into "index.php?page=two&data=x" like it does if I set the action to "pagetwo.php" (it turns into 'pagetwo.php?data=x' automatically)

Comment: Right, in that case the solution provided by "JamesL" and "mrtsherman" seems to be the way, i.e. create a hidden field in your form for storing the page number. Had your form submit type been "POST", it was possible to set action like "index.php?page=two"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem properly then you can add a hidden input with a value of `two` and name `page`. This will cause them to append to your url with the rest of your inputs.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="two" />
```

Comment: Actually the problem I was having is that when I set an action to a page like 'index.php?page=two' the input fields aren't getting picked up automatically in the URL like it would if I set the action to 'pagetwo.php'. I was hoping that 'index.php?page=two' would turn into 'index.php?page=two&data=x' just like 'pagetwo.php' turns into 'pagetwo.php?data=x'

Comment: @Xsecure then this is your solution. Set your action to index.php and add this hidden field. It will be appended automatically. The exact scenario you describe is not possible without javascript, but there is no need for that because you can do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the only reason you want to use GET is to keep track of what page the user is on.  Why not keep using POST and put a hidden field on each page if the form.

On page one:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value=1">
```

Two:

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value=2">
```

etc...

Comment: Actually the problem I was having is that when I set an action to a page like 'index.php?page=two' the input fields aren't getting picked up automatically in the URL like it would if I set the action to 'pagetwo.php'. I was hoping that 'index.php?page=two' would turn into 'index.php?page=two&data=x' just like 'pagetwo.php' turns into 'pagetwo.php?data=x'

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 options...

you can use hidden inputs or you can use SESSIONs or Cookies..

personally I'd use SESSIONs its easier to handle..

Comment: Session is one way to go about this but was hoping to avoid it because it would ruin the flow of the rest of the website.
The problem I was having is that when I set an action to a page like 'index.php?page=two' the input fields aren't getting picked up automatically in the URL like it would if I set the action to 'pagetwo.php'. I was hoping that 'index.php?page=two' would turn into 'index.php?page=two&data=x' just like 'pagetwo.php' turns into 'pagetwo.php?data=x'